# In mondodb query variables declared in $lookup are not working in pipeline $expr

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections

1. AdPlans
2. Tasks

Each task is related to AdPlan, In ad Plan I have number of columns, In the query I am using below AdPlan columns

1. drip_feed : Boolean
2. drip_feed_views : Number
3. drip_feed_interval : Number (Represent how many hpurs)

drip_feed  can be either true or false. Here is my ageegate query:

```
var adPlanWhere = [
        {
        $lookup :{
            from: 'tasks',
            let: { "adPlanId": "$_id", "drip_feed" : "$drip_feed", "drip_feed_views" : "$drip_feed_views", "drip_feed_interval" : "$drip_feed_interval"},
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { 
                            $and: [
                                    {$eq: ["$adPlan", "$$adPlanId"]},
                                    {$eq: ["$status", "Completed"]},
                                    {
                                        $or : [
                                            {
                                                $and : [
                                                    { $eq: ["$$drip_feed", true] },
                                                    { $gte: ["$updatedAt", moment(Date.now()).subtract(parseInt("$$drip_feed_interval"),'hours').toDate()] }, //this one is not working
                                                    { $lte: ["$updatedAt", moment(Date.now()).toDate()] },

                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                $and : [
                                                    { $eq: ["$$drip_feed", false] }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }

                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: 'adPlanTasks'
        }
    },
]
```

If `drip_feed` is true then I want to get only those tasks that are in `drip_feed_interval`